# Как узнать какой тип Fragmenta в Android?

Tags: java, android

Всем привет.

Есть три вида Фрагментов.

```
    ArtistFragment artistFragment = new ArtistFragment();
    AlbumFragment albumFragment = new AlbumFragment();
    SongFragment songFragment = new SongFragment();
```

Fragment один из трех выше предложенный возвращается с помощью функции.

```
Fragment fragment = pagerAdapter.getItem(position);
```

Как узнать какой Fragment вернулся? Смутно помню в Java была такая функция instanceOF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть два способа узнать класс фрагмента. Можно, как вы сами уже сказали, методом instanceof:

```
Fragment f = getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
if (f instanceof CustomFragmentClass) 
    //что-то сделать с f
```

А можно прикреплять к фрагменту специальный тэг, который будет уникальным для фрагмента каждого типа:

```
fragTrans.replace(android.R.id.content, myFragment, "MY_FRAGMENT");
```

В последствие, по этому тэгу вы сможете понять тип фрагмента:

```
MyFragment f = (MyFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MY_FRAGMENT");
if (f!= null && f.isVisible())
    //что-то сделать с f
```

Answer (score 1):

Да, можно с помощью instanceof. Например

```
Fragment fragment = pagerAdapter.getItem(position);
if(fragment  instanceof SongFragment)
{ //SongFragment }
else
{ //другой фрагмент}
```

Ещё можно имя класса получить так:

```
Fragment fragment = pagerAdapter.getItem(position);
String className=fragment.getClass().getSimpleName();
```

Answer (score 1):

ну да можно:

```
   Fragment fr =  pagerAdapter.getItem(position);
   if ( fr instanceof ArtistFragment) {
   // 
   } else if ( fr instanceof AlbumFragment) {
   // 
   } else if ( fr instanceof SongFragment) {
   // 
   }
```

а можно простой проверкой класса:

```
    Fragment fr =  pagerAdapter.getItem(position);
   if ( fr.getClass() ==  ArtistFragment.class) {
   // 
   } else if ( fr.getClass() ==   AlbumFragment.class) {
   // 
   } else if ( fr.getClass() ==   SongFragment.class) {
   // 
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Да конечно можно проверить с помощью instanceof, получится что то вроде

```
Fragment fragment = pagerAdapter.getItem(position);

if (fragment instanceof ArtistFragment) {
   ...;
} else if (fragment instanceof AlbumFragment){...}
```

Но вроде как использование instanceof не есть хорошо.
Как вариант можно у фрагментов устанавливать тэг, и по нему уже узнавать какого типа фрагмент.

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

```
if (fragment instanceof ArtistFragment) {
  //some actions for ArtistFragment
} else if (fragment instanceof AlbumFragment) {
  //some actions for AlbumFragment
} else if (fragment instanceof SongFragment ) {
  //some actions for SongFragment 
}
```